# Unable to understand these folders which got auto created in Eclipse while using selenium/cucumber

Tags: java, selenium, testing, cucumber

I am new to eclipse and was trying to create a small test case as a maven project and add cucumber functionalities to it. But whenever i run the code, two folders are getting created automatically. 1. Target/generated-sources/annotations and 2. Target/generated-test-sources/test-annotations. Can anyone explain why these files are getting created and what are these used for? Attached image -> [target/generated-sources/annotations issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilcoW.png)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**cucumber-reports** contains the normal execution report

**generated-test-sources** contains the dynamic runner class files which is created during the run time for parallel execution.